# To set multiple fonts in blackberry

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

How to set multiple fonts in blackberry? Actually we are using the following code to load the custom fonts to our application.

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Text-Italic.ttf");
FontManager.getInstance().load(is, "Text-Italic",
FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT) ;
```

If I want to set another font, Do I have to unload the current font or not?

Comment: How to unload the current font and set the another one font....

Answer (score 2):

No.  You don't have to unload the current font. You can add another custom font.

Thanks

Naveen M

Comment: S that file size 90 and above ttf files not able to load a?